# Google analytics goal getting triggered when it shouldn't be

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I've just setup a simple goal on my google analytics account.

When a user signs up to my membership, on success of account creation I have a database field 'first_visit' set to 1.

They then get taken to a welcome page. On that welcome page, I have some straight forward code that detects if that database 'first visit' flag is 1. If it is, a php $first_visit variable is set true on the page, and then a 0 is written into that field of the database.

The $first_visit variable controls if the google analytics tracking code is loaded.

```
<?php if($first_visit): ?>
<!-- google analytics tracking code -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

I've done this so the 'goal' will only be flagged once per user. But I open up my analytics and find multiple conversions taking place when I know they haven't?

The goal is setup as custom ->  Destination -> Equals to: http://subdomain.memebershipsite.com/welcome/

The subdomain and front blog are on the same domain.

Am I going about this the wrong way. Just because I am not loading the analytics code can google still somehow track they've been on the page, therefor flagging multiple conversions.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're conditionally outputting your GA code in this case. Instead of making the goal URL based, populate an event (in the condition you listed above) and do an event based goal.

```
<?php if($first_visit): ?>
<script>
  ga('send', 'event', 'Membership', 'First Visit');
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then set the goal to event based, with category equals "Membership" and action equals "First Visit" (or whatever values you set).

Comment: I thought I might have to go down the road of making it an event based conversion. Thanks for your input.